# JQuery can't trigger click second time and code freezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I tried to make and audio recorder wizard.

```
let reading_time = 3;
let delay_time = 3;
```

These are my time variables. I want to record audio after `delay_time` expires and stop recording when `reading_time` expires and then post the data to backend and repeat this until there is no more steps. But on second step, my canvas and whole code freezes and can't post the data second time.

```
$(stopBtn[currentIndex]).click(function () {
if (blobFile) {
  let formData = new FormData($(audioForm[currentIndex])[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: "/voice-recorder-2/save.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: (response) => {
      console.log("SENT!");
      if ($(".wizard-step.active").next().length > 0) {
        wizardNextStep();
        return;
      }
    },
    error: (xhr, status, error) => {
    //  console.error("Error:", error);
       console.log("SENT!");
      if ($(".wizard-step.active").next().length > 0) {
        wizardNextStep();
        return;
      }
    }
  });
}
});
```

I made disabled error catching because my backend is not online yet.

Here is the live codeepn link: https://codepen.io/Xteripus/pen/RwqmQqd?editors=0010

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The posted code doesn't seem to have anything related to audio recording, and doesn't use those variables.